# How to check if an array index exists using Ruby and/or Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Is there a Ruby (preferably) or Rails way to check if the second index of an array exists?

In my Rails (4.2.6) app I have the following code in my view that shows the first two thumbnails for an array of photos:

```
<% if array.photos.any? %>
  <%= image_tag array.photos.first.image.url(:thumb) %>
  <%= image_tag array.photos[1].image.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

However if there is no second item in the array, then there is an error

I've tried the following `if` statements to make the rendering of the second thumbnail conditional, but they don't work:

```
<% if array.photos.include?(1) %>
<% if array.photos.second? %>
<% if array.photos[1]? %>
<% if array.photos[1].any? %>
```

I figured that another way to get what I want would be to simply check the length of the array

Still I was wondering if Ruby (or Rails) had a method or way to check if a specific index in an array exists or not.  Thanks in advance

EDIT: To clarify I just want to show the first two thumbnails in the array, if any

Comment: Wenceslao's answer is good. The key to this is that in Ruby, Arrays can be accessed beyond their conceptual size safely. For example, for an array `a = [1]` you can check an index and if nothing is there, it will return `nil`. So `array.photos[1].nil?` is the easiest way to decide if anything is there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an .each, but if you want to follow this approach.
Instead of this:

```
<%= image_tag array.photos[1].image.url(:thumb) %>
```

Maybe you can use this:

```
<%= if(!array.photos[1].nil?) image_tag array.photos[1].image.url(:thumb) %>
```

Or:

```
<%= image_tag array.photos[1].image.url(:thumb) unless array.photos[1].nil? %>
```

Comment: Thanks, the `!array.photos[1].nil?` approach was what i was looking for

Comment: however i used different syntax with the `if` clause at the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

Here, why not

```
(0...array.photos.size).each do |photo|
    ......
end

array.photos.each do |photo|
    ......
end
```

Comment: because he's trying to access a specific index that he doesn't know will be occupied or not.